# Upload 7 files at once

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I create table to store pdf file on server
Fields : ProtocolPath ProtocolName ContractPath ContractName ContractXPath ContractXName
I have on asp.net page 3 Upload file control to take the file from user
After user click the button i handle the upload process by the following code:

```
 string FNProtocol = Path.GetFileName(UpProtocol.PostedFile.FileName);
                UpProtocol.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/UploadFiles\\Protocol" + "\\" + FNProtocol));
                string ImageProtocol = "/Protocol/" + FNProtocol.ToString();

                string FNContract = Path.GetFileName(UpContract.PostedFile.FileName);
                UpContract.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles\\Contract" + "\\" + FNContract));
                string ImageContract = "/Contract/" + FNContract.ToString();


                string FNEx = Path.GetFileName(UpEx.PostedFile.FileName);
                UpEx.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles\\Extention" + "\\" + FNEx));
                string ImageEx = "/Extention/" + FNEx.ToString();

 using (SqlConnection MyCon = new SqlConnection())
                {
                    MyCon.ConnectionString = ConnectString.OKS();
                    MyCon.Open();
                    SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand("insert into Images" +
                        "(ProtocolPath, ProtocolName, ContractPath, ContractName," +

                        " values (@ProtocolPath, @ProtocolName, @ContractPath," +
                        " @ContractName,@ContractXPath" , MyCon);

                    mycommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    mycommand.Parameters.Clear();


                   

                    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProtocolPath", ImageProtocol);
                    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProtocolName", UpProtocol.FileName);

                    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContractPath", ImageContract);
                    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContractName", UpContract.FileName);

                    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContractXPath", ImageCondition);
                    mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContractXName", UpCondition.FileName);
```

mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
Its working fine and save into database

My needs : When user want to download one of these file how i handle it
Is better create one table for each upload file or there are any solution because i tried retrieve the data in grid view but i am confused how to handle if user press download button he will download the specific files .

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to adopt some control that allows 1 or 20 files. It not really practical to "know ahead" of time how many files the user wants to up-load.

You can add Mutilselect = true to the file upload control, but really, there are SO MANY FANTASTIC file up load code and libraries on the internet. It thus makes LITTLE sense to build and re-create your own up-load system. I would adopt something like FilePond, or many other examples.

I use the ajaxtoolkit, and it also allows multiple files - and it nice since it allows files as un-limited size, and has a nice progress bar.

> it Is better create one table for each upload file

For sure you want to use a database. And no you will not have multiple tables. Just like we have a table of customers, we don't create a new table for each customer - quite much the WHOLE point of database, right?

The main issue is that when users up-load files, are they THEN able to download ALL or ANY files, or are they only to see/get/download ONLY THEIR OWN files?

If users MUST logon to the web site first, then this is easy, since then you can add a column (user_ID) to the database as to who the file belongs to (or are all users able to download any file - including ones they did not upload?).

With above information, then it becomes rather easy to display a grid view of their own files.

So, a database and single table for this purpose makes the most sense.

And yes, it is rather easy to display a grid view list of files to the user. You can then add a simple button to the grid for each row - clicking that button would then download the file - again very easy code.

So, now, back to the file up-load system. As noted, there are BOATLOADS of really fantastic file up-loaders - all ready for you to use. I would grab a cup of coffee, and google + try a bunch of samples - find one you like and find one that is "easy" to adopt. In other words, find one that fits your coding style, and the current extra libraries you are currently using (or willing to adopt).

As noted, I been using the ajaxtoolkit, and it has all kinds of cool dialogs, search as you type, and it also has TWO types of file up-load controls you can use.

Since I was already using the ajaxtoolkit (its for web forms), then I of course did not want to adopt another library into my application. However, the ajaxtool kit is quite a large system - a bit hard to justify JUST for the file uploader features.

So, I use the ajaxtoolkit "ajaxfileUpLoad" I suggest you don't cook up your own up-loader, since the many examples you find have a lot of nice extra features. (like a drag + drop hot zone to drag files onto the web page).

As noted, the ajaxtoolkit is a "big" library of controls and choices - probably over kill for JUST if you need a file up-load system. But, hey, maybe you are already using the ajaxtoolkit, and thus this decision is simple!

And better, is that "one" control can up-load 1, or 10 or 15 files, and for each file, you get "one" event, so you don't need loops, and multiple controls. (the amount of code you need is same for 1 file, or 15 files).

So, I would have two simple div, one to display the up-loader, and the other simple div to display the existing list of files.

So, say we have this markup:

```
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" 
                RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="rMyChoice"  
                AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem>Upload Files</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>My Files</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <br />

            <div id="uploadfiles" runat="server" style="width:35%">
                <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" 
                    OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" />
            </div>


            <div id="myfiles" runat="server" style="width:40%">
             <asp:GridView ID="GridFiles" runat="server" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns = "False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" CssClass="table">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="FileName"   />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UpLoadTime" HeaderText="UpLoaded" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdDelete" runat="server" Height="30px" 
                        ImageUrl="~/Content/ckdelete.png"
                        Width="40px" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="cmdDownLoad" runat="server" Text="Download" CssClass="btn" OnClick="cmdDownLoad_Click" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        </div>
```

So, we use a radio button list (like a fake tab control), the two divs.

So, we run the above, and we have this:

[image]

I hit up-load and all the files are up-loaded, and now we have this:

[image]

the code during up-loading was this:

```
    protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        // save file to up-loads folder

        string strSaveFile = Server.MapPath("~/UpLoadFiles/" + e.FileName);
        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(strSaveFile);

        // now add this row to data base

        string strSQL = "INSERT INTO MyUpLoadFiles (FileName, Size, UpLoadTime, User_ID) " +
                        "VALUES (@FileName, @Size, @UpLoadTime, @User_ID)";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = e.FileName;
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Size", SqlDbType.Int).Value = e.FileSize;
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@UpLoadTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("User_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session["User_ID"];
                conn.Open();
                cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }
    }
```

So, the uploader is nice, since it fires EACH time for each seperate file (no looping required).

And the code to display the up-loaded files, again simple (the radio button list click).

```
    protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            uploadfiles.Style.Add("Display", "normal");
            myfiles.Style.Add("Display", "none");

        }
        else
        {
            uploadfiles.Style.Add("Display", "none");
            myfiles.Style.Add("Display", "normal");

            GridFiles.DataSource = General.MyRst("SELECT * FROM MyUpLoadFiles ORDER BY UpLoadTime DESC");
            GridFiles.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

And the code to download a file when we click on it? Again, just a simple button click event, and this code:

```
    protected void cmdDownLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button myBut = sender as Button;
        GridViewRow gRow = myBut.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

        string strFileOnly = gRow.Cells[0].Text;
        string strFile = "";
        strFile = Server.MapPath(@"~/UpLoadFiles/" + strFileOnly);

        string sMineType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(strFileOnly);

        Response.ContentType = sMineType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFileOnly);
        Response.TransmitFile(strFile);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Note that GetMineMapping requires .net 4.5 or later.